# Чи ми можемо вживати слово "учбовий"

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

ЗМІ та деякі словники вносять слово "учбовий" в українську лексику. 
Інших слів на учб- немає в українській мові, чи може бути коректним його вживання у наукових матеріалах?

Answer (score 7):

В СУМ-11 присутні визначення та приклади вживання обох слів:

> **[НАВЧАЛЬНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/navchaljnyj)** **1**. Стос. до навчання, пов'язаний з ним. *У процесі навчання учні усвідомлюють не лише навчальні предмети, а й
>   свою власну навчальну діяльність* (Радянська психологічна наука..,
>   1958, 382); 
>   **2.** Признач. для навчання. *У вечірній і заочній системі треба ширше застосовувати сучасні технічні засоби.. — навчальне кіно, радіо,
>   телебачення, магнітофон* (Радянська Україна, 5.VII 1961, 3);
>
> **[УЧБОВИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/uchbovyj)** Те саме, що **навчальний**. *Київ тепер є найбільшим культурним центром республіки, в ньому працює Академія наук і Академія
>   архітектури, десятки вищих учбових закладів і наукових інститутів*
>   (Петро Панч, В дорозі, 1959, 264).

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/) зазначено:

> Замініть скалькований прикметник **учбовий** на стилістично кращий
>   варіант: **навчальний**.

Також на сайті [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53405/26222.html) рекомендують вживати

> **навчальний**: навчальний план, навчальне приміщення, навчальний заклад,
>   навчальна практика тощо.

На мою думку, в наукових матеріалах краще вживати слово **"навчальний".**

Answer (score 5):

Професор Олександр Пономарів [виступає проти використання слова *учбовий*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2010/08/post-28.html):

> Радіослухач Роман пише, що раніше було слово ВУЗ — вищий навчальний заклад, а тепер уживають ВИШ, чи правильно це?
>
> Річ у тім, що вищий навчальний заклад скорочено зветься ВНЗ; це літерна абревіатура, розрахована тільки на зорове сприймання і незручна для вимови, а ВУЗ — це вищий учбовий заклад. Слова «учбовий» немає в українській мові, це зіпсоване російське «учебный». Слово «ВИШ» постало внаслідок скорочення слів «вища школа», бо школа буває початкова, середня й вища. ВИШ широко вживали в пресі, в красному письменстві. Наприклад: «Потім ми вступимо у ВИШі, я — в Інститут авіації, а ти в хімічний» (Іван Микитенко). У часи зближення мов ВИШ замінено на російське слово ВУЗ. Тепер ВИШ посів належне йому місце в лексичному складі української мови.

Однак на сайті maidan.org.ua [з ним категорично не погоджуються](https://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1331746230.html):

> #### Навіщо було вбивати?
>
> Прикметник «учбовий» — питоме українське слово, утворене від іменника «учба».
>
> «Учба» — давньоукраїнське слово; рідко, але і тепер вживане.
>
> Наприклад, ним користується Олесь Гончар, зокрема, в романі «Людина і зброя» (наводжу дві цитати):
>
> 1. «Я вхопив чийогось коня та до свого, накинув посторонки і з гарматою — в парк! А в передку гільзи холості; і в нас усіх жодного патрона бойового — все холості в підсумках, з самим порохом. Для учби! Горобців лякати! Склади снарядів поруч, склади величезні. І тай, знаємо, боєприпасів сила. Коли, було, стоїш там в караулі вночі, то аж моторошно».
> 2. «Собачі маневри зараз біля радгоспу, учба на всю ніч, — пояснював дід Лука».
>
> Павло Штепа у своєму «Словникові чужослів» вказує: «учення — навчання, учба».
>
> Слово «учба» у свій час було запозичено російською (московською) мовою, його наводить у своєму тлумачному словнику Даль: «УЧБА, учебный, ученик и пр. см. учить». В статті «учить» Даль продовжує тлумачення: «Учба — вор. учёба новг. учоба кур. наука, ученье. Учеба не далась ему, и вынули из школы, нвг-борч. Учёб м. стар. ученье, выучка. За учеб взять 20 рублев». З цього можна зробити висновок, що від українського слова «учба» в російській (московській) мові було утворено діалектні слова «учёба», «учоба», «учеб». «Учеба» в рос. (моск.) мові довгий час було розмовним словом. Напр., сучасний словник Ушакова вказує: «УЧЁБА (или учоба), ы, мн. нет, ж. (офиц., разг., раньше простореч). 1. Действие по глаг. учиться, процесс обучения, ученье. Школьная у. Литературная у. Послать на учебу. Партийная у. 2. Муштра, дрессировка…».
>
> В рос. мові від слова «учеба» на початку ХІХ ст. було утворено прикметник «учебный» при назві щойно створюваних адміністративних округів — адміністративних одиниць, які на певній території об’єднували шкільні заклади, напр. «Киевский учебный округ». Українською мовою ця назва перекладалася «учбовий округ». Енциклопедія українознавства (Торонто, 1958) подає таку статтю: «Учбові округи, учбово-адміністративні одиниці в Рос. Імперії, створені 1803. На поч. 20 в. було 12 учбових округів, у тому числі на Україні три». Борис Антоненко-Давидович у книзі «Здалека й зблизька» (К., 1969) писав: «Коли куратором Київського учбового округу став видатний російський хірург і педагог М.Пирогов, почали робити вже й практичні заходи до переходу початкових шкіл на українську викладову мову». Цікавий такий приклад вживання Борисом Дмитровичем слова «учбовий», зокрема, у повісті «Слово матері» (цитата):
>
> «Після таких її вправ я повертався додому як очманілий. Мачуха, як і раніш, закликала мене до столу вечеряти, але мене нудило від її борщів та каш після маринадів, салатів, сирів, біфштексів та бефів караваєвської кухні. Про око я брався за підручник, але на розгорнутих сторінках я, замість літер і рисунків, бачив знову Мері. Таку загадкову, незрозумілу і тому, мабуть, ще більш знадну. Мачуха трохи побоювалась мене і ніколи не розпитувала, де я був і чого так змінився останнім часом. Настя допомагала мачусі по хазяйству, і їй ніколи було чіплятись до мене. Тільки батько став турботно, мабуть, не без впливу мачухи, приглядатись до мене, а може, вже й до нього дійшли чутки про мій занепад у класі. В його очах я так високо видерся в науку, що йому, малописьменному, ніяково було втручатися в мої учбові справи. Проте одного вечора він наважився мене спитати:
>   — Ну, як воно в тебе, Іване?..
>   — Та важкувато щось стало вчитись, тату… — невиразно, щоб менше брехати, відповів я, не підіймаючи від книжки очей».
>
> Допустимо, що Борис Дмитрович помилився, тож спробуємо його виправити чи поправити, тобто замінити «неправильне» слово «учбові» на «правильне» — навчальні. І що вийде: «В його очах я так високо видерся в науку, що йому, малописьменному, ніяково було втручатися в мої НАВЧАЛЬНІ справи». Дурниця вийшла, авжеж? Тобто у даному контексті правильним буде вживання лише слова «учбові».
>
> Останнім часом йде потужна кампанія витіснення з української мови слова «учбовий». Мовознавці посилаються, що то калька з рос. «учебный», позаяк в українській мові слова «учба» немає. Ми довели, що «учбовий» — то аж ніяк не калька, і слово «учба в укр. мові було і є. Зауважимо, що творення іменників за допомогою наростка «-б-» притаманне саме укр. мові, і таких слів є сотні, напр.: боротьба, ворожба, ганьба (прикм. ганебний), гурба, юрба, журба, злоба, молотьба, мольба, тяжба тощо. Такий цікавий приклад: Борис Грінченко подає лексему «судьба», але це не відповідник слову «доля», «судьба» за Грінченком від слова «судити» у значенні говорити про когось щось негативне, а «судебник» за Грінченком — людина, яка говорить про когось щось осудливе. Цікаво, що перший «Судебник» (як звід юридичних норм) з’явився 1468 року як збірник права Великого князівства Литовського, до складу якого входила Україна (відомий як Судебник вел. князя Казимира IV Ягеллончика. Інші судебники були укладені пізніше, саме Судебник Казимира IV дав поштовх для їхньої розробки. Зокрема, Судебник московського князя Івана ІІІ вийшов 1497троку Судебник Івана IV Васильовича (Івана Лютого) з’явився 1550 року, Судебник моск. царя Федора Івановича — 1589 р.
>
> Отже, ще раз наголошуємо: слово «учбовий» — питоме українське слово.
>
> І тут ми підійшли до ще одного принципового питання: «учбовий» і «навчальний» — синоніми-дублети чи ні?
>
> Ні, різниця між ними є. От Ожегов у своєму словнику слово «учеба» не тлумачить, а відсилає його до іншої лексеми: «УЧЕБА см. учиться». Зрозуміло, «учеба» — не «вчити», а «вчитися»? Далі, рос. слово «учеба» запозичено з давньоукр. «учба». Навчання укр. мовою — навчати, учба — вчитися, або ж вчити не «когось», а «щось», тобто інше значення цієї лексеми: «засвоювати, опановувати, намагатися запам’ятати, вивчати» (див. 4-том. Тлумачний словник укр. мови).
>
> Таким чином, «навчальний заклад» — заклад, де навчають (учителі), «учбовий заклад» — заклад, де вчаться (учні). Можна вживати і так, і інакше, для мови то тільки користь.
>
> Знищення в укр. мові слова «учбовий» вважаю дурницею. Була нормальна абревіатура — вуз. Ні, нам робити нічого, треба придумати неоковирне Ве-еН-Зе або ж ВиШ (вуха в'януть, язик заплітається і хочеться заплакати). Захищаємось від чого і кого?

Утім, коментатор «Максим Є.» погоджується з тією статтею лише частково:

> З пафосом статті погоджуюсь, але навіщо на правдиве твердження (що є таке слово і не варто його позбуватися) накручувати зайві міркування? Так, *учба*, *учбовий*, *учень*, *учитель* мають своє місце, що б не вигадував Пономарів, але це не питомо українські слова. Питомо українські були б закрити протезою (вучба, вученик), або одержали чергування (учити-вчити), а ці навіть своїм виглядом свідчать про запозичення з книжної мови, найімовірніше, під впливом російської. (*Учбовий*, напевно, з російської, а *учень*, ймовірно, запозичили з польської.)
>
> Слушно зазначено, що сьогодні за потреби можна вживати і *навчальний*, і *учбовий*. Також немає нічого поганого в різних способах: скороченнях *ВУЗ*, *ВНЗ* чи досить вдалому іменнику *виш* (від «вища школа» з 20-х років).